# "document.write" sobreescreve a página ao chamar função

Tags: javascript, funções

Ao puxar a função JS, os elementos da página somem e a table aparece. Como posso resolver o que está causando esse sumiço?

```js
function Gerar() {
  document.write("<table>");
  document.write("<tr>");
  document.write("<td>celula</td>");
  document.write("</tr>");
  document.write("</table>");
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="titulo">
    <h1>Caça-Palavras</h1>
    <form>
      Conteudo da pagina<br>
      <button onClick="Gerar()">Gerar</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normalmente `document.write` é usado em JS para compor partes de uma página **durante sua carga** (por sinal, seu uso é desencorajado por uma série de razões e efeitos colaterais).

Ocorre que sua função está sendo chamada **depois** do HTML original já ter sido servido e o DOM já montado. Isso faz com que implicitamente, na primeira ocorrência, seja chamado um `document.open`, efetivamente sobreescrevendo o documento original.

Da própria [documentação da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write):

> *Note: Because document.write() writes to the document stream, calling document.write() on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls document.open(), which will clear the document.*

que traduzido é:

> *Nota: à medida que document.write grava no fluxo de documentos, chamando document.write em um documento fechado (carregado) invoca automaticamente document.open, que limpará o documento.*

Mesmo resolvendo esta parte, ainda tem o problema do botão enviar o form (é o comportamento do `button`), o que pode não ser desejável nesse caso.

Isso se resolve com `<button type="button">` (dá para suprimir o evento de submit, mas melhor é nem disparar).

### Solução substituindo o `document.write` por `innerHTML`:

Uma possível solução para criar conteúdo em um documento já existente é substituindo o conteúdo HTML de um elemento.

Para fins de exemplo usaremos `<div id="output"></div>`, mas pode adaptar para qualquer elemento:

```js
function Gerar() {
  var output = document.getElementById('output');
  output .innerHTML = '<table>';          // Primeiro usamos =
  output .innerHTML += '<tr>';            // depois += para acrescentar
  output .innerHTML += '<td>CONTEUDO GERADO</td>';
  output .innerHTML += '</tr>';
  output .innerHTML += '</table>';
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form>
    Conteudo preexistente da pagina<br>
    <button type="button" onClick="Gerar()">Gerar</button>
    <div id="output"></div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Se fosse um conteúdo puramente textual, poderiamos usar `innerText`.

### Alternativamente, criando conteúdo diretamente no DOM:

Com `document.createElement` podemos criar qualquer elemento do HTML, e para inserir um elemento dentro de outro usamos `document.appendChild` (tem outras maneiras, mas vamos focar nessas bem corriqueiras):

```js
function Gerar() {
  var output = document.getElementById('output');
  var table  = document.createElement('table');
  var tr     = document.createElement('tr');
  var td     = document.createElement('td');
  td.innerText = 'CONTEUDO GERADO';
  tr.appendChild(td);
  table.appendChild(tr);
  output.appendChild(table);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form>
    Conteudo preexistente da pagina<br>
    <button type="button" onClick="Gerar()">Gerar</button>
    <div id="output"></div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```